# How to write a Copy Constructor for a Sprite?

Tags: c++, sprite, copy-constructor

My code crashes and I think I need to deep copy p_Texture and sprite.
I know how to make a deep copy of a pointer to an array but I'm not sure sure how to do this. Here I wrote this destructor:

```
class Sprite
{
private:
    IDirect3DTexture9* p_Texture;
    LPD3DXSPRITE sprite;
    D3DXVECTOR3 imagepos;
    int m_posX;
    int m_posY;
    int m_posZ;
    int m_width, m_heigth;

public:
    Sprite()
    {
    }

~Sprite()
{
    if (sprite)
    {
        sprite->Release();
        sprite = 0;
    }
    if (p_Texture)
    {
        p_Texture->Release();
        p_Texture = 0;
    }
}

Sprite(std::string path, int posX, int posY, int posZ, int width, int heigth)
{
    m_posX = posX;
    m_posY = posY;
    m_posZ = posZ;
    m_width = width;
    m_heigth = heigth;

    imagepos.x = posX;
    imagepos.y = posY;
    imagepos.z = posZ;

    D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx(p_Device, path.c_str(), m_width, m_heigth, D3DX_DEFAULT, 0, D3DFMT_UNKNOWN, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT,
        D3DX_DEFAULT, D3DX_DEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, &p_Texture)

    D3DXCreateSprite(p_Device, &sprite)
}

void draw()
{
    sprite->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);
    sprite->Draw(p_Texture, NULL, NULL, &imagepos, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    sprite->End();
}

void incPosX(int x) {imagepos.x += x;}
void decPosX(int x) {imagepos.x -= x;}
void incPosY(int x) {imagepos.y += x;}
void decPosY(int x) {imagepos.y -= x;}

float getPosX() { return imagepos.x; }
float getPosY() { return imagepos.y; }
```

};

However, it crashes because of copying it in the code.

Comment: Relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249279/copy-texture-to-texture

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a copy constructor is:

```
Sprite::Sprite(Sprite& other)
```

Then you just copy what you need from `other` to the `this` pointer.

Your code as it is right now has an implicit copy and move constructor. Both copy everything by value.
The reason for your crashing is likely because somewhere a copy or move of a `Sprite` is made, and when it expires the destructor is called. This frees some resources which you later attempt to use.

You can find such places by `delete`ing your copy and move constructors, and seeing where the compiler complains. The syntax follows:

```
Sprite::Sprite(sprite&  other) = delete; // no copy constructor
Sprite::Sprite(Sprite&& other) = delete; // no move constructor
```